# What is the closest function to R's nlminb in Python?

Tags: r, python-3.x, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

Python `scipy.optimize.minimize` function supports the following methods:

- Nelder-Mead
- Powell
- CG
- BFGS
- Newton-CG
- L-BFGS-B
- TNC
- COBYLA
- SLSQP
- trust-constr
- dogleg
- trust-ncg
- trust-exact
- trust-krylov

Which method is closest to R's `nlminb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nlminb` is an unconstrained and bounds-constrained quasi-Newton method optimizer. This code is based on a FORTRAN PORT library by David Gay in the Bell Labs. As for Pyhon quasi-Newton menthods are:

> **Unconstrained minimization**
>
> Method BFGS uses the quasi-Newton method of Broyden, Fletcher, Goldfarb, > > and Shanno (BFGS) [5] pp. 136.
>
> **Bound-Constrained minimization**
>
> Method L-BFGS-B uses the L-BFGS-B algorithm [6], [7] for bound
>   constrained minimization.

L-BFGS-B  & BFGS, being a member of quasi-Newton family methods, are the closest analogs of `nlminb`.