# The closest Python's scypy solver analog to R's nlminb?

Tags: python, r, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I know Python has the following solvers in`scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
Nelder-Mead
Powell
CG
BFGS
Newton-CG
L-BFGS-B
TNC
COBYLA
SLSQP
trust-constr
dogleg
trust-ncg
trust-exact
trust-krylov
```

However they are all similar, which method is the closest analog to R's `nlminb`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the closest function to R's nlminb in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759606/what-is-the-closest-function-to-rs-nlminb-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlminb` is an unconstrained and bounds-constrained quasi-Newton method optimizer. This code is based on a FORTRAN PORT library by David Gay in the Bell Labs. As for Pyhon quasi-Newton menthods are:

> **Unconstrained minimization**
>
> Method BFGS uses the quasi-Newton method of Broyden, Fletcher, Goldfarb, > > and Shanno (BFGS) [5] pp. 136.
>
> **Bound-Constrained minimization**
>
> Method L-BFGS-B uses the L-BFGS-B algorithm [6], [7] for bound
>   constrained minimization.

L-BFGS-B  & BFGS, being a member of quasi-Newton family methods, are the closest analogs of `nlminb`.